# Ubuntu Terminal launch applications on different workspace

Tags: terminal, workspace

I am trying to write a group of bashscripts to launch a set of applications on different workspaces. Reason being so that I can for example set up a script that launches all my dev related applications on the workspaces I usually put them on.

I am looking for a command like

```
ws -2 foo
```

Which would launch the foo application on workspace 2

I tried looking through google but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some window managers can do this, do you have a particular WM in mind or are you looking for a WM-agnostic solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Devil's Pie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie) will allow you to specify rules to move application windows to different workspaces.